# Activity getting destroyed while launching new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

```
Intent showImage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageViewerActivity.class);
startActivity(showImage);
```

why is MainActivity is getting destroyed (onDestroy() called) , while launching a new activity?

Comment: first, add the error's log cat to undestand what kind of problem you have...

Answer (score 2):

Your activity is destroyed either because system is running out of space or because you called finish() on MainActivity somewhere.

You can read the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

> The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can
>   happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
>   finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
>   instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between
>   these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Comment: I am testing  the app on an emulator and not calling finish() explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Your  activity is getting destroy because you create a new context  in your  invocation , you should do this:

```
Intent showImage = new Intent(this,ImageViewerActivity.class); 
startActivity(showImage);
```